# Decomposing $\mathcal{B}(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and let $\mathcal{B}(H)$ be the (C*/W*-)algebra of bounded operators on it. Actually, you may forget about the involution in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ because I am interested in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ only as a Banach algebra (operator algebra).

Do there exist two **infinite-dimensional** Banach algebras $A, B$ such that $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is isomorphic as a Banach algebra to the **projective tensor product** $A\otimes_\gamma B$?

Comment: Now cross-posted to MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108188/tensorial-decomposition-of-bh

Comment: I just now that the projective tensor product oh $H$ and $H^*$ is B(H).

Comment: @AliBagheri Sorry, that's wrong:
The completed projective tensor product $H\hat{\otimes}_\pi H$ 
is really "much smaller" than $\mathcal{B}(H)$ because it
equals $\mathcal{l}^1(H)$, the Trace-class operators on $H$.